# Datatables not working for realtime update of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I tried using datatables plugin and it worked smoothly for my table. I have this one problem: when I try to refresh my function for getting the value from database using `$interval` every seconds, it destroys the whole table and I cant use the search and pagination because the whole table refreshes,

**What I tried and doesn't work:**

```
statesave();
destroy();
```

**Here is my code for realtime update of data using datatables:**

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$interval', function($scope,$interval) {
  $interval(function () {
    $scope.register = {
      regData: {
        branch: {},
      },
      names: [
        {name:"narquois"},{name:"vorpal"},{name:"keen"},
        {name:"argol"},{name:"long"},{name:"propolis"},
        {name:"bees"},{name:"film"},{name:"dipsetic"},
        {name:"thirsty"},{name:"opacity"},{name:"simplex"},
        {name:"jurel"},{name:"coastal "},{name:"fish"},
        {name:"kraken"},{name:"woman"},{name:"limp"},
      ],
    };
    }, 1000);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 10,
    
    });
})
</script>
  

<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in register.names">
            <td align="center">{{ person.name }}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: use `setInterval (datatables.ajax.reload, 1000);` https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49038/refresh-table-every-1-second

Comment: @Jeremy You should instead go for an angular wrapper for this datatables, it will save you a load of time and effort, if its implemented the angular way!

Comment: @NarenMurali can you give me some good datatables for angular?

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera I use this one! [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)

Comment: I wouldn't use that function if I were you believe me, it will consume a lot of memory just for a table. There are a lot of API for real-time table, use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use that function if I were you believe me, it will consume a lot of memory just for a table. There are a lot of API for real-time table, use them.

Comment: Is there any api that you recommend?

Comment: Read the docs here: https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/initialisation/realtime.html